# Button Visibility bound to a property is not getting updated

Tags: wpf

I have a class (not the ViewModel) which has a property that determines the Visibility of a button. I have included the class in the UserControl's Resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <helpers:DialogLayoutConfigInfo x:Key="DialogConfigInfo"/>
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I have the button's visibility bound to a property in "DialogLayoutConfigInfo" class.

```
private bool isButtonVisible;
public bool IsButtonVisible
{
   get { return isButtonVisible; }
   set { isButtonVisible= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonVisible"); }
}

<Button Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource DialogConfigInfo}, 
Path=IsButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
```

If I update the property "IsButtonVisible" in the constructor of "DialogLayoutConfigInfo" class, the Visibility is updated. But when the constructor is called, I don't have the XML file (which is used to get the information to set the property). So I call a function that updates the property later. Why isn't the visibility getting updated if I set it in the function?

The function that sets the property is called from my View's code behind.

Comment: Is IsButtonVisible set in a secondary thread? Also, based on your posted code, it seems that `DialogLayoutConfigInfo` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. However, can you confirm that too?

Comment: No. It is not set in a secondary thread and Yes. It does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: show your `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

Comment: I have used the converter that comes with the `PresentationFramework`. I haven't implemented it on my own. The converter doesn't seem to be the problem since it works when I set the property in the constructor.

Comment: does your setter from `IsButtonVisible` get executed, if you change his value not in the constructor?

Comment: Yes. I put a breakpoint to check that. The setter gets executed.

Comment: maybe you are using a different object from Typ `DialogConfigInfo` so it would make sense if it only works if you set the value in the constructor

Comment: Ah! Yes. You are right. I'm stupid to have not realized that! But how do I solve this problem now?

Comment: how do you call the function of DialogLayoutConfigInfo from your code behind?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your  DialogLayoutConfigInfo class like this

```
public class DialogLayoutConfigInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Property Change Event
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Property Change Method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prop">Property Name</param>
    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    public static DialogLayoutConfigInfo instance;

    public DialogLayoutConfigInfo()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        IsButtonVisible = Visibility.Visible;

    }
    private Visibility isButtonVisible;
    public Visibility IsButtonVisible
    {
        get
        {

            return isButtonVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            isButtonVisible = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsButtonVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

And the code behind should be like

```
DialogLayoutConfigInfo.instance.IsButtonVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically it implements by built-in class in .Net [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Example:**

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Hello, I am the button" Visibility="{Binding ShowButton, Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Your class:

```
private bool _showButton = false;
public bool ShowButton
{
   get { return _showButton; }
   set
   {
      if (value != _showButton)
      {
         _showButton = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ShowButton");
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to change the `Visibility` of your `Button` in code, you can make it by this code in ViewModel:

```
//Show error Message
IsButtonVisible = false;
```

**Your case:**

It is not necessary to implement `IValueConverter`as `Visibility` is altered perfectly without `IValueConverter`(see example above) by built-in [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) in **.Net**. Your case:

```
private bool isButtonVisible;
public bool IsButtonVisible
{
    get { return isButtonVisible; }
    set { isButtonVisible= value; OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonVisible"); }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible", Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I have added a "BooleanToVisibility" converter. Check my XAML. The Visibility is updated if I set the property in the constructor. Only if I set the property in a function it is not udpated.

Comment: I know that. But I set the properties from information in the XML. It is in Boolean in the XML. So I have to use a converter anyway. Conversion doesn't seem to be the problem since it works when I set it in the constructor.

Comment: Based on best practice you **must not** use UI-Elements in your VM, so using `System.Windows.Visibility` is not recommended

Comment: It's just a function that sets the property. It is called from the code behind.

Comment: @WiiMaxx thank you very much! You've opened my eyes! I've updated my code.